# How to login and download a file in perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to login to the site using Mechanize in Perl script. It does log into the index page but I try to get the content of the page where file hyperlinks are present then I am not logged in I assume that after looking at the content of the page

Secondly, How can we download a file from the indirect hyperlink of a file which directs to some action which then downloads a file. Please guide, as there is not much help available for this particular use case

Below is my code

````
use LWP;

my $username = 'user'; 
my $password = 'pass';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech -> cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech -> get('some_website/index.html?#');
$mech -> form_name('form');
$mech -> field ('user' => $username);
$mech -> field ('password' => $password);
$mech->submit();
$mech -> get('actual_page_address_with_file_hyperlinks?adfgenDispatchAction=examine&idProgressivo=0&idFlusso=4200212');
#print $mech-> content();

$mech->save_content("result.html");

my @links = $mech->links();
for my $link ( @links ) {

    #if(index($link->text,"Scarica")!= -1)
    #{
    printf "%s, %s\n", $link->text, $link->url;
    #}
}```
````

Comment: This can't be the actual code though? It uses a module (`WWW::Mechanize`) which it never loads, so it won't even compile.  (While you don't use `LWP` which you load, and which on its own wouldn't do anything -- would need `LWP::UserAgent`.)

Comment: By some of the description it appears that the site uses JavaScript?  It'd be helpful to know which site it is.

Comment: @zdim, LWP loads LWP::UserAgent

Comment: @ikegami OK, but it doesn't actually do anything per se; one has to use `LWP::UserAgent`.

Comment: @zdim, Yes, the first part of what you said was accurate.

Comment: @ikegami  Well, thanks for the comment, to set things straight -- there is indeed nothing wrong with `use LWP;` (and then work with `LWP::UA`...), what my comment "kinda" implies

Comment: (I mean my comment might imply that _there is_ something wrong with that...)